# Break loop after every third iteration

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, reactjs

I have an array `arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]`.

I want to print

```
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

So I will need to break the loop after each third element.

```
let s = '<ul>';
arr.forEach(el => {
  s += '<li>' + el + '</li>';
});
s += '</ul>';
```

Comment: Could be solved with a *nested* loop, i.e. a loop within a loop.

Comment: Are you sure it is reactjs?

Comment: You *cannot* break a loop via using `forEach`. Try `for` or `while` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of breaking loop, you can split array in chunks and create your HTMLString accordingly.

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function getULStructure(arr) {
  let s = '<ul>';
  arr.forEach(el => {
    s += '<li>' + el + '</li>';
  });
  s += '</ul>';
  return s
}

function createHTMLString(arr, count) {
  var _htmlString = ''
  while (arr.length > 0) {
    _htmlString += getULStructure(arr.splice(0, count))
  }
  return _htmlString
}

var _html = createHTMLString(arr, 3);
document.querySelector('.content').innerHTML = _html
```

```html
<div class="content">
</div>
```

Comment: Too complex. Just `for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { if (i === 3) {} }`

Comment: @TânNguyễn Note: *"each third element"*.

Comment: @TânNguyễn This is more modular. You can reuse `getULStructure` to get dynamic ul list of any number. But if you wish to get of specific count, `createHTMLString` can be used.

Comment: `arr[3]` would assign to the fourth element. If `if (i === 3)`, creating new `<ul/>` tag and adding to the string, otherwise, continuing creating `<li/>` tag.

Comment: @TânNguyễn both approaches are fine. The difference is, in your approach, you will have to hard-code or patch `3` to handle cases. Here I have exported non dependent part to an external function. So there is a separation of concern. One function will take care of creating `ul`s and other function will take care of controlling sections. Again, both are fine. Its just a personal choice.

Comment: Bad idea! Look at your code. You need 2 functions, 2 loops and `have to` splice `arr` before generating an html tag. If I were you, i wouldn't do that.

Comment: @TânNguyễn Its all right. You can add your own answer with your approach. As I said, its a personal choice.

Comment: Nope. OP can do that via reading my comments. I just vote for you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check this simple solution, which uses a single loop without any break statements to create the HTML content that you want.

```js
function generateTemplate(items, splitPoint) {
  var template = '<ul>';

  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i] === splitPoint) {
      template += '</ul><ul>';
    }

    template += '<li>' + items[i] + '</li>';
  }

  template += '</ul>';

  return template;
}

var container = document.getElementById('container');
var items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var template = generateTemplate(items, 4);
container.innerHTML = template;
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
}
ul li {
  background-color: #E6E6E6;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple solution.

This uses `slice` to extract the first 3 element and runs a recursive call until the array is finished

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]



const itrate = (arr) => {
  var firstThree = arr.slice(0, 3)
  var rest = arr.slice(3, arr.length)
  var ul = document.createElement('ul')
  firstThree.forEach((el) => {
    if (el) {
      li = document.createElement('li')
      li.innerHTML = el
      ul.appendChild(li)
    }
  })
  var node = document.getElementById('app')
  node.appendChild(ul)
  if (rest.length > 0)
    itrate(rest)
}

itrate(a)
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can `break` iterations only when using `for` or `while` loops, they are the standard javascript way to iterate.

by the way, if you want to template over an array, in my opinion, `Array.prototype.reduce` is the best way to fit what you want...

```js
/**
 * @param {any[]} list
 * @param {int} breakIndex
**/
function compileHtmlLists(list, breakIndex) {
  
  return list
    .reduce(function(tpl, item, i, list) {
      var last = i === list.length - 1;
    
      item = "<li>" + item + "</li>";
    
      if(i === breakIndex) {
        item = "</ul><ul>" + item;        
      }
    
      if(last) {
        item += "</ul>";        
      }
    
    
      return tpl.concat(item);
    }, "<ul>")
  ;
}

var view = compileHtmlLists(
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  5
)

console.log(view);
```

Comment: I also prefer `reduce`, but the number of items can vary, so I don't think this solution works

Comment: If you need to break the list at some (variable) point, it can be done via reduce...